# Sonata admin ignores "required" attribute

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 application that uses the Sonata admin bundle.  In one of my entities' `configureFormFields()` method, I have the following:

```
        ->add('market',
            'entity',
            array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => 'MyCompany\AppBundle\Entity\Market',
                'choices' => $query = $this
                    ->entityManager
                    ->getRepository(Market::class)
                    ->findBy(['status' => 100])
            ,
                'placeholder' => 'no_selection',
                'required' => true,
                'label' =>  $this->trans('country_of_origin', [], 'messages'),
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'jsb_ jsb_GetDealersForCountry jsb_HideOtherTabs',
                    'data-jsb' => json_encode(array(
                        'url' => $this->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/dealers/country/id/'
                    )),
                )
            )
        )
```

... but I find that I am able to save without any value in the 'market' field.

Here is the annotation over the market property in my entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyCompany\AppBundle\Entity\Market", cascade={"persist"})
 *
 */
private $market;
```

**So anyway, is there a simple way to make this field truly mandatory?**

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer below link and create your custom validation for market field in admin class

[sonata admin validation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/conditional_validation.html)

Answer (score -1):

Here is how my annotations now look:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyCompany\AppBundle\Entity\Market", cascade={"persist"})
 * @Assert\Count(min=1)
 *
 */
private $market;
```

This change comes courtesy of the Symfony documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/NotNull.html